# Управление воспроизведением id тега HTML5 <audio>

Tags: javascript, html5, аудио

Есть список формируемых элементов audio с уникальным id:

```
<audio class="song" preload="auto" id="id-92" controls="controls">
     <source src="../uploads/f2e49d34edc7fd037d2930f8d86552d5.mp3">
</audio>
<audio class="song" preload="auto" id="id-93" controls="controls">
     <source src="../uploads/f2e49d34edc7fd037d2930f8d86552d5.mp3">
</audio>
```

Я нашел следующий код на [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20719550/play-one-html-audio-element-at-a-time) javascript:

```
$(function(){
$('audio').on('play', function() {
    $('audio').not(this).each(function(index, audio) {
        audio.pause();
    });
});
```

Он позволяет останавливать текущий воспроизведенный элемент audio, если начинается воспроизведение другого элемента audio. Пожскажите как его можно улучшить, что бы по окончанию воспроизведения одного, воспроизводился следующий?

Comment: Уже столько раз освещался такой вопрос, (не только на этом сайте) но что мешает использовать на странице только один элемент аудио, а для перехода на другой трек только менять его **src**? При одном элементе накладка просто невозможна.

Comment: @Олег, опыт, все дело в нем. даже иногда нужен опыт что бы найти нужную информацию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let songs=[];
document.querySelectorAll('audio').forEach(audio =>{
  songs.push(audio.id);
  audio.addEventListener('play', function(e){
  document.querySelectorAll('audio').forEach(elem =>{
    if (elem.id != e.target.id){
      elem.pause();
    }
  })
  })
audio.addEventListener('ended', function(e){
  let next = songs.indexOf(e.target.id) + 1;
  songs[next] === undefined ? next = 0 : songs[next]
  let nextSongs = document.getElementById(songs[next]);
  nextSongs.play();
})
})
```

```html
<audio class="song" preload="auto" id="id-92" controls="controls">
     <source src="https://html5book.ru/examples/media/track.mp3">
</audio>
<audio class="song active" preload="auto" id="id-93" controls="controls">
     <source src="https://html5book.ru/examples/media/track.mp3">
</audio>
<audio class="song" preload="auto" id="id-94" controls="controls">
     <source src="https://html5book.ru/examples/media/track.mp3">
</audio>
```